# Convert Entity class to a lot of DTOs

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a project where I need to store Users on database. I'm using Hibernate and in some part of module also Spring Data JPA experimentally. 
I have a REST endpoint for register customer and I'm receiving there UserDTO object. After that in other service I need to convert it to UserEntity and save in database.

Now I created user settings page where I need to display some information about logged user. I don't want to sent UserDTO object because there is to much data so I need to create one more DTO class and Converter class. I feel it's a little bit tricky because every time when I wan to store or receive some specific data, I need to create new DTO and converter class so I have a lot of DTOs and Converters in my project. When I will need to change something on my Entity class, probably I will need also change a lot of converters.

Is this correct way or do you have any better solution for that?

Comment: Don't convert entities to dtos return the dtos from your query directly. Saves memory, increases performance and saves the converter.

Comment: But the question is how? I found only solution like this: https://smarterco.de/spring-data-jpa-query-result-to-dto/ . It's working but it's also strange because for huge object with composition, I will have to create constructors with all fields... For small use case I think this example is okay but not for much bigger class.

Comment: You can use result mappings instead of constructors. Fact is you have to express the mapping some where, either constructor or predefined mappings.

Comment: Could you show me some example?

Comment: If you have spring data jpa you can use "Interface-based Projections" from here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces also you can give a try to http://modelmapper.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can use projection queries to create your DTO-s without converters.

Here is a short example with explanation: [JPA - Basic Projections](https://dzone.com/articles/jpa-basic-projections)

Comment: I feel this solution is worst than Converters. For small use case it's maybe okay but not for huge class with a lot of fields.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you need. E.g. if you have to create many DTO-s from the same entity at a time it is better to load the entity itself then create the DTO-s with converters (so you will have only one DB call), if you need only a few attributes of the entity and you want to create only one DTO from it, then projection query is a good choice (you don't load the whole /big/entity into the memory and you don't have to create an extra converter class).